# Drawing Basic Animations in Python

Tags: python, animation, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Hello I am trying to create something like this [box with controllable dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfauK.png)
I need to be able to move and interact with the dots. I have tried turtle and pyglet, but neither of them seem to do what I want them to do.

Turtle is letting me create dots but it doesnt seem to play well with oop. I'm a super noob at python oop so maybe I'm just doing it wrong but I can't seem to make an turtle object that I can actually use how I want. I would ideally be able to use my own methods built off of the turtle methods, and create and call on data unique to each turtle.

```
import turtle
import time
import random

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("simulation")
wn.bgcolor("tan")
def rng(whatisrandom):
    match whatisrandom:
        case 'coords': return(random.randint(-400,400) , random.randint(-400,400))
        case 'heading':return(random.randint(0,359))
        case 'forward':return(random.randint(0,50))
    
class bug():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self = turtle.Turtle(shape = "circle",visible=False)
        self.speed(0)
        self.penup()
        self.setpos(rng('coords'))
        self.showturtle()
        self.speed(1)
        self.forward(20)
        
    def move(self):
        self.setheading(rng('heading'))
        self.forward(rng('forward'))
    
bug1 = bug()
bug1.move()


wn.mainloop()



this is the error message.
self.setheading(rng('heading'))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'bug' object has no attribute 'heading'
```

I ultimately want to animate these little bugs with neural nets and train them to do different movements, and eventually interact with each other.

Comment: Why are you using mainloop if you have no `onkey` or `onclick` events, or any events that could possibly be triggered/fired after `mainloop` is called? It's not clear what you are expecting to happen. Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.mainloop) for any of those methods? Can you be clear about what you actually are having trouble with? Your post is super vague. `I can't seem to make an turtle object that I can actually use how I want` is not clear. If you want to have a list of objects that get updated each frame, you need to write the logic.

Comment: I was trying to add logic from within the bug class but I can't seem to access the Turtle object I created with any methods in the bug class. I've updated the post with more of my actual code so far that is not working.

Comment: "I need to be able to move and interact with the dots" -- what sort of interaction and movement, exactly, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a misunderstanding of how to subclass an object in Python.  Let's rearrange things a bit:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

class Bug(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(shape='circle', visible=False)

        self.speed('fastest')
        self.penup()
        self.setposition(Bug.rng('coords'))
        self.showturtle()
        self.speed('slowest')
        self.forward(20)

    def move(self):
        self.setheading(Bug.rng('heading'))
        self.forward(Bug.rng('forward'))

    @staticmethod
    def rng(whatisrandom):
        if whatisrandom == 'coords':
            return randint(-400, 400), randint(-400, 400)

        if whatisrandom == 'heading':
            return randint(0, 359)

        if whatisrandom == 'forward':
            return randint(0, 50)

        return None

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Simulation")
screen.bgcolor('tan')

bug1 = Bug()
bug1.move()

screen.mainloop()
```

I don't have an issue with your `match` statement, I'm just unfamiliar with it and haven't updated my Python sufficiently!

Comment: Yes! this was exactly what I was looking for! I figured my class was just jacked up. Thanks a bunch!